# Given an array with maximum sum, locate two number which produce the maximum sum without exceeding the maximum

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code that counts the number of pairs in an array that have a sum below the maximum,

```
def findPairs(arr, x):
 
    l = 0; r = len(arr)-1
    result = 0
 
    while (l < r):
     
        if (arr[l] + arr[r] < x):
         
            result += (r - l)
            l += 1
         

        else:
            r -= 1
 
    return result
     
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n = len(arr)
x = 7
print(findPairs(arr, x))
```

I need to edit it in order to return a list of the pair with the maximum sum not exceeding the maximum parameter (x). If there are multiple pairs with the maximum sum then one pair is chosen at random

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: "I need to edit it in order to..." Okay; and **what is your question** about this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations) method to get all possible combinations of a list.

```
from itertools import combinations

def findPair(arr):
    allcomm = combinations(arr,2)
    allcomm = filter(lambda e:sum(e)<=max(arr),allcomm)

    return max(allcomm,key=sum)

        

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


print(findPair(arr))
```

output

```
(1, 7)
```

---

1. First I use [`itertools.combination`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations) method to the all possible combination of an array.
2. I use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) method to get only the pair whose sum is less than the max number in the arr.
3. Then I use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) function to get the maximum sum pair in the `allcomm` array.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional modules (which would potentially make the implementation more efficient) you could just do this:

```
def find_pairs(arr, m):
    c = 0
    pair = None
    for i, x in enumerate(arr[:-1]):
        for y in arr[i+1:]:
            if x + y < m:
                c += 1
                pair = x, y
    return c, pair

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
m = 7

print(find_pairs(arr, m))
```

**Output:**

```
(6, (2, 4))
```